# Trying to ID a VHS anime compilation, including an episode of "Vampire Princess Miyu", and a sci-fi horror anime with two characters fighting in armor

Tags: story-identification, anime

I had this two-hour VHS tape back in 2006 with a compilation of four episodes from different anime. One episode was from *[Vampire Princess Miyu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_Princess_Miyu)*. The other was a sci-fi horror anime with two characters fighting in the woods in armor. I really want to watch that other anime, but I can't find anything on the VHS, and it was an official release too. If you have any info on this let me know.

Comment: _"two characters fighting in the words in Armor"_...? Did you mean two characters fighting in the _woods_? Also, which country was this compilation released in?

Comment: Yes ,that's what I meant and it was released in America

Comment: [The Guyver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guyver:_Bio-Booster_Armor)? If that's not it, then you need to provide more details.

Comment: Do you know if the Vampire Princess Miyu episode was from the OVA or the TV series? Was it dubbed or subbed? And could you tell if it was the American dub or the UK one, if it was the OVA?

Comment: American Dub. I've never seen either versions. It was the episode with the guy from the flower shop begging the vampire to turn hin then he fell off the side of a building.